# Add whitespace before and after a string in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I want to add a whitespace before and after random strings.

I have tried using "Random_string".center(1, " ") but it doesnt work.

Thanks

Comment: `str.ljust(int)` and `str.rjust(int)` were the methods I was looking for when I came to this post. [More info on those here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-ljust)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My ruby is rusty, but IMO nothing wrong with the easy way

```
def pad( random )
    " " + random + " "
end

padded_random_string = pad("random_string")
```

using center

```
"random_string".center( "random_string".length + 2 )
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `pad("random_string")`?

Answer (score 6):

I find this to be the most elegant solution:

`padded_string = " #{random_string} "`

Nothing wrong with taking the easy way.

Comment: This is the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 4):

```
irb(main):001:0> x='Random String'
=> "Random String"
irb(main):002:0> y=' '+x+' '
=> " Random String "
irb(main):003:0> x.center(x.length+2)
=> " Random String "
```

The parameter to [`center`](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ref_c_string.html#String.center) is the total length of the desired output string (including padding).

Comment: based on the docs, you don't need the second argument to center, but I didn't test, so it could be wrong :)

Comment: @Lucas- The second parameter, if present, is a string to use as the padding character(s).  If it is omitted, whitespace is used.  I think that was an addition in Ruby 1.8, and that link might be referencing version 1.6.

Comment: right.  I should have stated that you didn't need it to fulfill his request, since based on his question, he wants to append space.

Answer (score 4):

I mean, is there some reason that you can't just do this?

```
padded_string = ' ' + random_string + ' '
```

Answer (score 1):

"Random_string".ljust("Random_string".length + 4).rjust("Random_string".length + 8)
or 
"Random_string".ljust(17).rjust(21)  # where "Random_string" is 13 characters long

using .ljust method with .rjust method

Comment: In other words, just .ljust plus the .rjust methods together